# Javascript -- Attach events in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding ‘click’ event listeners in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909652/adding-click-event-listeners-in-loop)

I make a demo.So let's see the HTML first.

```
<a href="#" id="testA">testA</a>
<a href="#" id="testB">testB</a>    

<div id="showA">showA</div>
<div id="showB">showB</div>
```

And i want to bind `click` events to Elements `a` . and when it clicks, `alert` the related `div`. (click `id="testA"`,alert `id="showA"` ...)

And i write the jQuery code.

```
var arr = ["A","B"];    
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    $("#test"+arr[i]).click(function(){
      alert($("#show"+arr[i]).text())
    });
  }
```

But it doesn't work. I debug this code and find that this code `alert($("#show"+arr[i]).text())`

only run when I click the `a` element . and when I click `a` . the variable `i` is `3` already.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that once the event handler is executed, `i` will have reached its final value and be stuck at `arr.length`. You can use a closure to capture the value of `i` at each iteration of the loop:

```
var arr = ["A","B"];    
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $("#test"+arr[i]).click(function(){
            alert($("#show"+arr[i]).text())
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/DHrk6/).

Comment: is it called infamous loop problem???

Answer (score 2):

The easiest/cleanest solution would be to use a `forEach` loop instead.

```
arr.forEach(function(val) {
  $("#test"+ val).click(function() {
    alert($("#show"+ val).text())
  });
});
```

If you want support for older browsers there are many polyfills online.

**Edit:** Since your using jQuery you can also do it with `$.each`:

```
$.each(arr, function(idx, val) { ... });
```

Comment: You can even add `HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach; NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;` so you can forEach HTMLCollections and NodeList. Nice Solution!