# Javascript loop not creating jquery controls correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace:

```
    var linuxControls = ["CreateLinuxUser", "EditLinuxUser", "DeleteLinuxUser", "Export"];
    $("#dlgCreateLinuxUser").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    $("#btnCreateLinuxUser").click(function () {
        $("#dlgCreateLinuxUser").dialog("open");
    });
    $("#dlgEditLinuxUser").dialog({
      autoOpen: false
    });
    $("#btnEditLinuxUser").click(function () {
        $("#dlgEditLinuxUser").dialog("open");
    });
    $("#dlgDeleteLinuxUser").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    $("#btnDeleteLinuxUser").click(function () {
        $("#dlgDeleteLinuxUser").dialog("open");
    });
    $("#dlgExport").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    $("#btnExport").click(function () {
        $("#dlgExport").dialog("open");
    });
```

with:

```
    for (i = 0; i < linuxControls.length; i++) {
        var strDlg = "#dlg" + linuxControls[i];
        var strBtn = "#btn" + linuxControls[i];
        $(strDlg).dialog({autoOpen: false});
        $(strBtn).click(function () {
            $(strDlg).dialog("open");
        });
    }
```

However it is only creating the last control "Export." As looping constructs and string building goes, it all looks fine. Is there something weird with jquery that is preventing this?

Comment: With the loop you're basically overriding each control until you hit your last control which is Export.

Comment: Without looking closer on you code, one obvious problem is the `$(strDlg).dialog("open");` this code is executed at the time when the click event happens, but at that time, the value for `strDlg`  is the same for all the click callbacks.

Comment: probably a duplicate to: [Javascript - Attach events in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227360/javascript-attach-events-in-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a closure loop so that `i` won't be changed at runtime, can do that with jQuery `each`.

```
$.each(linuxControls, function(i) {
    var strDlg = "#dlg" + linuxControls[i];
    var strBtn = "#btn" + linuxControls[i];
    $(strDlg).dialog({autoOpen: false});
    $(strBtn).click(function () {
        $(strDlg).dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you! :D C++ Engineer  learning web programming. lol.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're jQuery already why not try something similar to this:

```js
$('.linux-control').click(function() {
  $('#' + $(this).data('dialog')).dialog("open");
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnCreateLinuxUser" class="linux-control" data-dialog="dlgCreateLinuxUser">Create User</button>
```

### Edit

The above snipped binds `.click()` to all `.linux-control` classes. It then looks for the `data-dialog` attribute and creates a jQuery selector to open your dialog. In the instance above the button contains `dlgCreateLinuxUser` in the `data-dialog` attribute of the element. No loops needed since the `.click()` function is bound only to element that fires it but listens for all elements with the class `.linux-control`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please walk me through what this is doing exactly? I am new to jquery.