# iterate through all available getElementsByClassName nodes

Tags: javascript, undefined, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

For my project, I am required to get the collection of all the elements which have the same class. So, I am doing it with `getElementsByClassName`.

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

if (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var tab = tabs[i];
        console.log(tab);    // which outputs as 'undefined'..
        console.log(i);    // which outputs the nos of the total nodes available with class 'tab'
    }
}
```

I have to retrieve all those elements(which has class 'tab') and apply it another class (say 'bat')..

My question is, why it consoles out undefined as above?? and how can I be able to iterate through all the required nodes sequentially. Is there any code available which can do this??

**EDIT ::**

Forget to add it..

When clicked on any tab which has `'tabs'` class, it always returns the same result..

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

if (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var tab = tabs[i];
        tab.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log(tab[i]);  // always returns undefined
            console.log(tab);  // always returns the last element in the list
            console.log(i);  // always returns the length of that list (in my case its 3)
        }, false);
    }
}
```

How can I be able to iterate through all the available elements sequentially.

Comment: What's the output of console.log(tabs)?

Comment: console.log(tabs) provides the list of all the available elements with class-name 'tab'..

Comment: Works as expected [here](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/rxWGEL) - logs each tab, followed by 0, 1, and 2.  Can you show a non-working example?

Comment: Is that the actual code above?

Comment: epascarello, The edited code is my actual code..

Comment: `tab[i]` is definitely a typo for `tabs[i]`. Beyond that, take a look at [adding 'click' event listeners in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909652/adding-click-event-listeners-in-loop) to learn about closures and how they're giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can change a NodeLiist into an array. Btw, your `tab[i]` should be `tabs[i]` I think.

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
var tabArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(tabs);
for(var i = 0; i < tabArray.length; i++) {
     console.log(tabArray[i].id);
     console.log(i);
     tabArray[i].innerHTML = "t"+(i+1);
     
};
```

```html
<div id="t1" class="tab">t</div>
<div id="t2" class="tab">t</div>
<div id="t3" class="tab">t</div>
<div id="t4" class="tab">t</div>
<div id="t5" class="tab">t</div>
<div id="t6" class="tab">t</div>
<div id="t7" class="tab">t</div>
<div id="t8" class="tab">t</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with getElementsByClassName(), as said in [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) the return is a array-like object not a array. Another point is that return is a live HTMLCollection so if you want to change the class name through a loop the collection will be live updated on the fly and will cause unexpected behaviors.
I made a example with class change case. Check complete code on link below.

http://codepen.io/renatocolaco/pen/VemMNy

```
function btnClick(event){

event.preventDefault();

//action goes here
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

console.log("fouded elements: " + boxes.length);
var element = boxes.item(0);
while(element){
    element.className = "another_box";
    element = boxes.item(0);
}

//doesn't work
//var cache = boxes.length;
//for(var i = cache; i < boxes.length; i++){
//    console.log(boxes[0]);
//    boxes[0].className = "another_box";
// }

//doesn't work
//Array.prototype.forEach.call(boxes, function(element, index, array){

    //array[index].className = "another_box";

//});
}
```

Update:
The second problem, when you are adding event to the tabs, you have a closure problem.
This is because, at the point that the onclick method is invoked (for any of the tabs), the for loop has already completed and the variable i already has a value(the size of your collection).

Wrap your code inside a self executed function like this:

```
(function (i) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log(i); });
})(i);
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you used JQUERY before?  That might be an easier path.  This way you can use $(".tab").  You can also use .forEach() instead of a for loop?  Might make it more simple

Also, Paul's example seems to be working, can you provide a non working JSfiddle?

Comment: No, I have not used jquery before.. Now trying your suggestion of ,forEach() ..