# Uncaught TypeError inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects (players), and those objects have a method `increment` that increments an object variable.

Inside a `for` loop, when I call
`players[x].increment();` I get the following error:

> intex.html:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of
>   undefined

```
for (var x = 0; x < players.length; x++) {
    $("#button-" + x).click(function() { //I select one of the buttons
        players[x].increment(); //Here is the problem 
      //This part forwards doesn't matter
        $("#score-" + x + "-n").text(players[x].score);
        if (players[x].score >= 10) {
            alert(players[x].name + " WINS!");
            $("#alertz").html('<div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align:center;" >' + players[x].name + 'WINS!!!</div>');
        };
    });
};
```

When I call for example `players[0].increment();` outside the loop, I do not have any problem.

In case it isn't clear. I have a simple page with two buttons. Based on what button I press, it increments, and display a variable.

When I use `console.log(var)` at the `increment` part, I get a 2, but `players[2]` doesn't exist, so I think that is the problem, but I do not know for sure or how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding 'click' event listeners in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909652/adding-click-event-listeners-in-loop), or perhaps even better dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: When you click on the button, `x` is equal to `players.length` which is more than the number of `player` objects. You must `bind` x to the function, referencing in this manner will only produce the last value of `x` for all click events.

Comment: You don't need to have click event in a loop.. Thats not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iterator is equal to players.length when the click event is fired, and the click handler then uses that iterator in an attempt to access an index that is out of range for your players array.

Try putting an index attribute on your button like this instead:

```
<button class="player-button" data-player-index="0">Increment</button>
<button class="player-button" data-player-index="1">Increment</button>

$('.player-button').click(function() {
    var index = $this.attr('data-player-index');
    players[index].increment();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to frontend, but indeed, it was stupid to put the click event in a for loop.