# Loop through array and add event listener "click" to each

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I'm trying to iterate through an array of of elements and add an event listener to each one.

Populating the array:

```
var sliders = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("sliderControlLi"));
```

Iterating through the array:

```
sliders.forEach(function (i){
  addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("you clicked slider controler " + this.index + "!");
  });
});
```

But with this code, whenever I click on any of the sliders I get multiple console.log printouts - once for each slider in the array.

I've looked for similar problems, but I'm still unable to solve this one.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And what is `addEventListener`? Where are you referencing the element to add the onclick?

Comment: Use `i.addEventListener(..)` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Related [adding 'click' event listeners in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909652/adding-click-event-listeners-in-loop)

Comment: Do you mean that it should be `sliders[i].addEventListener("click"`...? If I do this, then I get an error that "sliders.addEventListener is not a function"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use **[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** as :

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
```

You could also get the index from **[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** :

```
arr.forEach(function ( element_value,element_index ){ })
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var sliders = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("sliderControlLi"));

sliders.forEach(function (element, index){
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("you clicked slider controler " +index + "!");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="sliderControlLi">slider 1</div>
<div class="sliderControlLi">slider 2</div>
<div class="sliderControlLi">slider 3</div>
<div class="sliderControlLi">slider 4</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using

```
EventTarget.addEventListener(...)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so in your case

```
sliders.forEach(function (elem){
    elem.addEventListener(...);
});
```