# Keep parameter value assigning Event Listener on loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, scope, addeventlistener

I have a `while` loop that attaches an Event Listener (`SelectRua()`) to a `div`.

I was needing the `div` inner text inside `SelectRua()` method, and since the `div` is what's calling the Event Listener, this worked fine:

```
$('#div' + i).on("click", function () { SelectRua(this) })
```

And like so i easily accessed the `div` attributes when it is clicked.

But now i want to assign an object (variable) that will no longer be available when the click on the `div` occurs:

As i saw in [adding 'click' event listeners in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909652/adding-click-event-listeners-in-loop) and [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) i was able to reach this code, after many tries:

```
while (morada[i]) {
$('#div' + i).on("click", function (morada) {
    return function (morada) { SelectRua(morada[i]) }
    }(morada))
}
```

When the `div` is clicked, the `SelectRua()` method is called, but the parameter is `undefined`, although i put it everywhere in this example.

So my question is, how can i set the value of the parameter when it's assigned to the Event Listener the be used when the event is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace that `click` event with:

```
$('#div' + i).bind("click",morada[i],SelectRua)
```