# Random Background Color by clicking on paragraphs.My code gives an Error

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, addeventlistener

I am doing a homework exercise which is to color the background of my paragraphs randomly by clicking on them. The thing is, when I tried my code, I receive an Uncaught Error " Cannot Read property 'style' of undefined. I tried to break my head but I really don´t understand what I am doing wrong. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset=utf-8/>
        
    </head>
    <body> 
        <section>
            <p>Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Cevadis im ampola pa arma uma pindureta. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim.</p>
            <p>A ordem dos tratores não altera o pão duris. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi. Praesent malesuada urna nisi, quis volutpat erat hendrerit non. Nam vulputate dapibus. Vehicula non. Ut sed ex eros. Vivamus sit amet nibh non tellus tristique interdum.</p>
            <p>Leite de capivaris, leite de mula manquis sem cabeça. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem cochilar e fazendo pose. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis. Não sou faixa preta cumpadi, sou preto inteiris, inteiris.</p>  
        </section>
        <script>
        
            (function(){
               'use strict'
                
                var $ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
              
                 for(var i = 0; i<$ps.length;i++){
                     
                    $ps[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                        
                         $ps[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
                    });
                 }
     
                 function colors(){
                     var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
                     var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
                     var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)); 
                     var color = 'rgb'+'('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
                }

            })();
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `$ps[i]` inside the event listener function. But the value of `i` updates after every iteration of the loop. At the end of the loop, the value of `i` is equal to the value of total number of paragraphs. The index of paragraph starts from 0. So there are (Total number of paragraphs - 1) paragraphs. That's why, when it tries to access `$ps[i]`, it causes error!

You can fix this by using `this` keyword instead of `$ps[i]` inside the event listener function. Here `this` keyword indicates the element where event listener inserted.

You have simply used `color` inside the event listener function. But color is a local variable inside `colors()` function. You can not access a local variable outside of the function. So you have to use `colors()`. Also you need to return the color at the end of `colors()` function.

```
for(var i = 0; i<$ps.length;i++){     
    $ps[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = colors();
    });
}


function colors(){
    var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)); 
    var color = 'rgb'+'('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
    return color;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and explanation =)

Comment: Welcome @Raquel Santos :)

Answer (score 0):

In the click listener function your element is reachable by "this".

Otherwise you color function was not called because you forgot the "()" and return the result in the function.
The aboce snippet yould work. Is this what you'r loocking for ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset=utf-8/>
        
    </head>
    <body> 
        <section>
            <p>Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Cevadis im ampola pa arma uma pindureta. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim.</p>
            <p>A ordem dos tratores não altera o pão duris. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi. Praesent malesuada urna nisi, quis volutpat erat hendrerit non. Nam vulputate dapibus. Vehicula non. Ut sed ex eros. Vivamus sit amet nibh non tellus tristique interdum.</p>
            <p>Leite de capivaris, leite de mula manquis sem cabeça. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem cochilar e fazendo pose. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis. Não sou faixa preta cumpadi, sou preto inteiris, inteiris.</p>  
        </section>
        <script>
        
            (function(){
               'use strict'
                
                var $ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
              
                 for(var i = 0; i<$ps.length;i++){
                     
                    $ps[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                        
                         this.style.backgroundColor = colors();
                    });
                 }
     
                 function colors(){
                     var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
                     var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
                     var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)); 
                     return 'rgb'+'('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
                }

            })();
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909652/adding-click-event-listeners-in-loop/8909792#8909792

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and explanation =)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with how `var`'s are treated inside the loop - that is, every time your 'click' listener is being called, the `i` variable is checked again - and as the loop was already finished, it's exactly the length of your HTML elements array. You can check it by changing the inside of the event listener to simple `console.log(i)`. It will print 3 every single time.
How to fix it? You can, for example, take the information of what was the clicked element from the event that is passed to your function:

```
var $ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');

function changeBackgroundColor(e){
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors();
}

for(var i = 0; i<$ps.length;i++){

  $ps[i].addEventListener('click', changeBackgroundColor);
}

function colors(){
  var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
  var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
  var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)); 
  return 'rgb'+'('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
}
```

Also take note that your `var color = (...)` will not be seen outside of the scope of the function. You need to actually return it and read the returned value.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and explanation =)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

I'm not sure why you'd use a function closure to execute this but that's not really an issue.

Creating a function `colors` without calling it wouldn't set the `var color` you had inside, which means you couldn't use it, so I added a return value in order to get a new color every time the function is called.

The last thing was the issue with `$ps[i].style`: because you used a `var i`, the `ps$[i]` you use within the event listener won't be the same even it is called from, change the style of the target of the event instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset=utf-8/>
        
    </head>
    <body> 
        <section>
            <p>Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Cevadis im ampola pa arma uma pindureta. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim.</p>
            <p>A ordem dos tratores não altera o pão duris. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi. Praesent malesuada urna nisi, quis volutpat erat hendrerit non. Nam vulputate dapibus. Vehicula non. Ut sed ex eros. Vivamus sit amet nibh non tellus tristique interdum.</p>
            <p>Leite de capivaris, leite de mula manquis sem cabeça. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem cochilar e fazendo pose. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis. Não sou faixa preta cumpadi, sou preto inteiris, inteiris.</p>  
        </section>
        <script>
                'use strict'
                
                 var $ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
              
                 for(var i = 0; i<$ps.length; i++){
                    $ps[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
                         e.target.style.backgroundColor = color();
                    });
                 }
     
                 function color(){
                     var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
                     var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
                     var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)); 
                     return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
                 }
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and explanation =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset=utf-8/>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <section>
            <p>Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Cevadis im ampola pa arma uma pindureta. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim.</p>
            <p>A ordem dos tratores não altera o pão duris. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi. Praesent malesuada urna nisi, quis volutpat erat hendrerit non. Nam vulputate dapibus. Vehicula non. Ut sed ex eros. Vivamus sit amet nibh non tellus tristique interdum.</p>
            <p>Leite de capivaris, leite de mula manquis sem cabeça. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem cochilar e fazendo pose. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis. Não sou faixa preta cumpadi, sou preto inteiris, inteiris.</p>  
        </section>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
          if( target.tagName !== 'P' ) return;
          const rand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          target.style.background = "rgb(R,G,B)".replace(/R|G|B/g, rand);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```